# Changing devserver website port

Tags: asp.net, .net

I'm reading basic wcf service [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97204/Implementing-a-Basic-Hello-World-WCF-Service) and I'm stuck at host project. Here is advised to change `asp.net dev. server port number`.

I cannot access those properties since this is all I have in my prop. window
[image]

Answer (score 1):

select project name from the solution explorer and then right click--> properties..IN the properties window goto web tab.In the second division ther is a specific radio button for "specific port"..select that and give your own port no..

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know what version of visual studio you are using, but in VS 2013 you right click on the WCF service project, select Properties, and then go to the Web section. There you can select what IIS version you wish to host the service in. If you select IISExpress you can enter url with port of your choice.